# Linq query to find all orphan products

Tags: c#, linq

I have three models for a product and product category system:

```
[Products]
Id
Title
Info
Price

[ProductCategories]
Id
ParentId
SortOrder
Title

[ProductsInCategories]
Id
ProductId
ProductCategoryId
SortOrder
```

Now, I want to make a list of all products which doesn't have an entry in the ProductsInCategories table. I.e., all orphan products. How can I do that in linq?

Comment: You could start by trying something and showing us that code?

Comment: @Stian - reply if Tim solution solves your problem or not? When you ask a question you should accept the answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: Only knowing the tables isn't enough. That's why showing your own efforts, however tentative, is always useful. They often clarify things you didn't realize were relevant. Like: which ORM are you using? What do the LINQ classes look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `!Any` to get only those without an entry in `ProductsInCategories`:

```
List<Product> productList = db.Products
    .Where(p => !db.ProductsInCategories.Any(pc => p.Id == pc.ProductId))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: with ToList() possible?))

Comment: My downvote: this can't be answered without knowing OP's ORM and class model. Who says that `ProductsInCategories` is even present as class? Also, using navigation properties should be promoted.

Comment: My Upvote :  Because as per the problem, this solution is perfect one... based on a ORM model. There are multiple answers but this is one among them.

Comment: @GertArnold: works with Linq-To-Objects and any LINQ provider i know. OP mentioned he uses LINQ and that he has three entities (he called them models). Your suggestion about navigation properties is correct, but this is an assumption about the LINQ provider OP is using. My solution works with any provider

Comment: @ChandanKumar and Tim: Using `p => !p.ProductsInCategories.Any()` would be much cleaner and should be recommended. But whether that's possible requires a bit more info of OP's coding environment.

Comment: @GertArnold: 1) you make an sssumption about the provider, how you know there is  an navigation property at all? 2) Even with navigation properties. This table is an n-m relationship. So there is no navigation property

Comment: *how you know there is an navigation property at all?* Exactly, that's my point. If there is one, it should be used. So ask for details before answering a question. A working solution isn't always the best solution. As for 2) It's probably not modelled as m:n with a hidden junction class (because of the `SortOrder` column), But again: who knows? But it's relevant.

Comment: @GertArnold: you complain about me because i  made assumptions about the model(which OP has shown) and the ORM(my approach works with any). Now you provide a way that works only in few ORM's and LINQ providers and that is better? I don't think my query is too complicated, it's still very readable.

Comment: *If* there is a better solution why not try to scope it out? It only takes a bit more patience. A solution that "always works" isn't necessarily the best in a specific environment. Anyway, I think I've made my point. Good luck!