# LINQ to select all orphaned children in a list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am working with the following model in C#

```
public class Bill
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Document Document { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to select all the `Payments` with no parents, using LINQ.

I am aware of the following technique from several SO answers, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47791130):

```
List<Payment> paymentList = db.Payments
    .Where(p => !db.Documents.Any(d => d.Payment.Id == p.Id))
```

but this works if `Document` contains only one `Payment`, not an entire list.

Do you know how to adjust the query to retrieve all the orphaned Payments?

Comment: If you had a navigation property back to the parent aka document. Then it would be easy as  `db.Payments.Where(p => p.Document == null)`

Comment: @TheGeneral - I was thinking the same thing when I saw this. It is why many ORMs will create the list, even though it does not exist in the underlying data. Allows for iteration (like this code), but also keeps the integrity of the Payment objects.

Comment: `.Where(p => !db.Documents.Any(d => d.Payments.Any(p2 => p.Id == p2.Id)))` would be one, very inefficient approach. See duplicates. Much better would be to go ahead and create a data structure that maps from `Payment` objects back to the parent `Document` object, if not in the database, then at least built in memory as needed to perform this kind of filtering.

Comment: thanks both for chipping in, unfortunately I cannot make any modification since I am reverse engineering an API into a DB and I need to keep it 1:1 with the source. I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22182809/5258201) might solve my issue anyway. @PeterDuniho I tried your solution before asking here, but I felt there was something deeply wrong with it :D

Comment: @andreucci Why don't you add a foreignKey `DocumentId` to `Payement` Table?

Answer (score -1):

Well, at least one thing EFC to be better than EF6 is that it allows you to access the [shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) in LINQ queries using [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-3.1) method.

In this particular case, the shadow FK property. So you could use something like this

```
.Where(p => EF.Property<Guid?>(p, "DocumentId") == null)
```

The drawback is that you need to know the exact shadow property name and type, and compiler won't help you for that.

Answer (score -1):

```
 // All the payments whose id is not contained in any of all the           
//Documents.Payments
   List<Payment> paymentList = db.Payments
        .Where(p => db.Documents.SelectMany(d => d.Payments)
        .All(p2 => p2.Id != p.Id));
```